# Spring boot yml property file processing

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

Spring boot's yml proerty file is very convenient but it seems it won't work in this situation

```
filterChainDefinitionMap:
  /v1/user/platform/login: "anon"
  /v1/user/login: "anon"
  /v1/shop/**: "anon"
  /**: "user"
```

The map key can not be parsed by spring boot's property processor. I escaped them with `"/v1/shop/**"` but doesn't help. Can someone give some advice?

Comment: `it seems it won't work in this situation` **Did you try?**

Comment: I tried but the key `/v1/shop/**` can not be parsed. I wonder if it needs to be escaped?